# Steam not default position error

Tags: 18.04, wine, steam

When I try to install Age of Empires 2 HD on PlayOnLinux with steam version 
I have this error:

```
Error in POL_Shortcut
Binary not found: steam.exe
Have you installed the program to the default location?
```